# Custom color of Lightning progress indicator not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-progressindicator, lightning-progressstep

**HTML**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="test color">
        <lightning-progress-indicator type="path" current-step="2" variant="shaded" class="custom_css">
            <lightning-progress-step label="Step 1" onclick={launchFlow} value="1"></lightning-progress-step>
            <lightning-progress-step label="Step 2" onclick={launchFlow} value="2"></lightning-progress-step>
            <lightning-progress-step label="Step 3" onclick={launchFlow} value="3"></lightning-progress-step>
            <lightning-progress-step label="Step 4" onclick={launchFlow} value="4"></lightning-progress-step>
        </lightning-progress-indicator>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS**:

```js
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { FlowAttributeChangeEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';

export default class LightningPath extends LightningElement {
    @api showFirstScreen = false;
    @api showSecondScreen = false;
    @track step = 4;


    launchFlow(event) {
        this.step = event.target.value;
        console.log('Path value', this.step);
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```css
.custom_css {

    --lwc-colorbackgroungPathCurrent: red;
    --lwc-colorbackgroungPathIncomplete: purple;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathCurrentHover: red;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathComplete: red;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathCompleteHover: red;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathIncompleteHover: purple;
}
```

Previouly color was working after summer 23 release it is not working. Please suggest some other way to change the color of steps.

Comment: can you show your html code please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct variable names (in camelCase):

Use `--lwc-colorBackgroundPathCurrent` instead of `--lwc-colorbackgroungPathCurrent` and `--lwc-colorBackgroundPathIncomplete` instead of `--lwc-colorbackgroungPathIncomplete`

Comment: Hi @Sneh
I am facing the same issue and tried your way but still didn't work. Only two of the property --lwc-colorBackgroundPathComplete and --lwc-colorBackgroundPathCompleteHover is working, other doesn't seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the custom CSS that you need to add to your code.

```
.custom_css {

    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathActive: green;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathActiveHover: gray;

    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathComplete: yellow;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathCompleteHover: black;   
    
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathIncomplete: white;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathIncompleteHover: blue;

}
```

For the currently selected path you need to use `--lwc-colorBackgroundPathActive` and for the hover you need to use `--lwc-colorBackgroundPathActiveHover`.

For the Incomplete, you can use the `--lwc-colorBackgroundPathIncomplete` and `--lwc-colorBackgroundPathIncompleteHover`. I have tried to use this but some css will override it.